# Node JS Minification

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

Minification process on JavaScript as per definition basically just removes blank spaces , comments . Building on this , why in Nodejs is language specification pertaining to whether code is written in ECMA5 or ECMA6 necessary ? Why not just run the minifier and minify the code by removing blank spaces and comments. Why do I need to bother whether my code is written ECMA5 OR 6 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think ES version matters?

Comment: My code base is mix of ECMA5 & 6 .I used gulp-uglify and it gave errors which on further finding were because we used ECMA6 language specs which gulp-uglify failed to minify.

Comment: You use uglify for backend?

Comment: Yes offcourse.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify , I have used this. Do you have the answer for my question ?

Comment: (Minification is much more than you think), btw: [babili](https://github.com/babel/babili) is an `ESNEXT` minifier.

Answer (score 3):

> Minification process on JavaScript as per definition basically just removes blank spaces, comments.

I have no idea whose "definition" you are quoting. Minification is **much, much** more than squeezing out white space. Minifiers parse the entire source in order to do advanced minification. Obviously, to do that, they have to know the syntax they are parsing. If they don't know ES6 syntax, they cannot parse ES6 input. To minify ES6, you'll have to choose a minifier that supports ES6.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but can you just give some examples of what extra things does it do apart from removing blank spaces and comments which need language specification adherence .

Comment: There are many, many examples. A very simple one is `true` becoming `!0`. Another is `if (false) {LONG_PIECE_OF_CODE}` being removed entirely. Of course, neither of those is ES6-specific, but both require the code be parsed, and the minifier can only parse syntax it knows.